# Macro that adds object to array in compile time?

Tags: rust

I want to create a list of static compile time generated variables. That is, when the program starts, they are already there and I don't need to mutate it.

Currently I'm doing like this:

```
pub type ProfilerInfo = (&'static str, &'static str);

pub const Fps: ProfilerInfo = ("fps", "Frames Per Second");
pub const DecodingElapsed: ProfilerInfo = ("det", "Decoding Elapsed Time");
pub const DecodedPerSec: ProfilerInfo = ("dps", "Decoded Per Second");
pub const BytesPerSec: ProfilerInfo = ("bps", "Bytes Per Second");

pub const ALL_VARIABLES: &'static [&'static ProfilerInfo] = &[&Fps, &DecodingElapsed, &DecodedPerSec, &BytesPerSec];
```

however this is error prone, I could forget to add one of the variables on the list `ALL_VARIABLES`.

Is there a way to create a macro that creates a `ProfilerInfo` and adds to `ALL_VARIABLES`?

Context: why I need this? Well, this list is to be returned by the command line like this `my_program --list-variables`, so it's nice for it to be done when the app starts.

I don't think it's possible with an array like I did on the top but maybe with a `Vec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a macro that creates the `ALL_VARIABLES` static slice for you.

```rust
pub type ProfilerInfo = (&'static str, &'static str);

macro_rules! profiler_variables {
    ($(pub const $id:ident: ProfilerInfo = $rhs:expr;)*) => {
        $(
            pub const $id: ProfilerInfo = $rhs;
        )*
        pub const ALL_VARIABLES: &'static [&'static ProfilerInfo] = &[$(&$id),*];
    }
}

profiler_variables! {
    pub const Fps: ProfilerInfo = ("fps", "Frames Per Second");
    pub const DecodingElapsed: ProfilerInfo = ("det", "Decoding Elapsed Time");
    pub const DecodedPerSec: ProfilerInfo = ("dps", "Decoded Per Second");
    pub const BytesPerSec: ProfilerInfo = ("bps", "Bytes Per Second");
}

fn main() {
    for (name, descr) in ALL_VARIABLES.iter() {
        println!("Variable: {}, description: {}", name, descr)
    }
}
```

Output:

```rust
Variable: fps, description: Frames Per Second
Variable: det, description: Decoding Elapsed Time
Variable: dps, description: Decoded Per Second
Variable: bps, description: Bytes Per Second
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53beb6b7ea22cce4a6a4035cbfd0a49a)

Comment: I didn't know I could match with patterns on macros, thanks